# How to change Status bar color with Event

Tags: ios, swift, uistatusbar

I know change status bar color with under the code.

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .default // or.lightContent
}
```

But for example, if I use this code with IBAction, how can write the right code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want your status bar's appearance to change, you can call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` on your view controller. In your `@IBAction` example:

```
@IBAction func changeStatusBarStyle() -> Void{
    // Do whatever you need to determine and set the next status bar style
    setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}
```

Note that if you call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` within an animation block, the style change will be animated

Answer (score 0):

Set that the status bar needs to be updated when you click on the button. In this way 'preferredStatusBarStyle' will be called.

```
setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
```

Comment: preferredStatusBarStyle's example is this?    func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
        return UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
    }